# Firebase - How do I check the project creator

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I have been added to a project as an editor,

can I check who actually started this project ?

I had a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/templates but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the [Users and Permissions](https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/_/settings/iam) panel in the Firebase console, you can find the owner(s) of the project. While those may not necessarily be the creator, they *are* the people that can at this moment do most to manager the project.